# Rails adding a controller for an new table in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rails-migrations

In rails, I have used migrations to make a new database table. It has an id, name, description, and a user_id (it has a foreign key to the user table).

I am very new to rails, and would like to know if there is a standard way to generate a controller for this new table.

This code will be added to an already existing/functioning site, so building it all with the traditional scaffolding tutorials doesn't seem to be the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic command to generate controllers

```
rails generate controller controller_name
```

You can create actions manually through editor or you can generate through command as well which is

```
rails generate controller controller_name index new
```

you can generate all actions after specifying controller name in the command

Answer (score 0):

**use this command**

`rails g controller ControllerName`    (Controller name must be singular)

Comment: This is wrong.  A controller name needs to be plural: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#controller-naming-convention